# Sum of Time differences while having times in 6 different columns

Tags: sql, sum

I have following database

```
 Station|Status | Start_hour | Start_minute | Start_second | End_hour | End_minute | End_second
```

Is it possible to sum up times for every entry that has end_ fields filled between given time?

Example:

```
Station|Status|Start_hour|Start_minute|Start_second|End_hour|End_minute|End_second
8      |  0   |   10     |    5       |    0       | NULL   | NULL     | NULL 
8      |  1   |   10     |    5       |    0       | 10     | 15       | 30
2      |  1   |   9      |    53      |    0       | 10     | 16       | 45
7      |  0   |   10     |    23      |    0       | NULL   | NULL     | NULL
```

So the output would look like this:

```
Sum of time
29:15 */sum of times for stations 8 and 2(5:30 + 23:45)/*
```

Problem? I have to do it in single query

Comment: SUM(end_time - start_time)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh yes I know about the SUM command, but I completely don't know how to use it while having hours, minutes, seconds separately

Comment: Build up valid time values, for end and start, then compute the difference and sum. (You should have time data types columns, instead of separate columns. If you can't alter the table, create a view!)